# Issue in pulling pages from the database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am having problems pulling the pages through in PHP and HTML I have used :-

```
    <li>
     <!-- Pulling Categories from the database 
     dynamically -->
<?php 
    $nav_subjects = find_all_subjects(['visible' => $visible]);

    while($nav_subject = 
        mysqli_fetch_assoc($nav_subjects)) { 
?>
    <span class="opener"><?php echo h($nav_subject['menu_name']); ?></span>
```

Which pulls the categories dynamically from the database and displays them with a drop down arrow just how I wanted but the pages will not show underneath them here's the code I have used for that bit:-

```
<!-- Categories listed correctly let's pull the pages for each one -->
<?php 
    if($nav_subject['id'] == $subject_id) {
        $nav_pages = find_pages_by_subject_id($nav_subject['id'], ['visible' => $visible]); 
        while($nav_page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nav_pages)) { 
?>
    <ul>
    <li>
    <a href="<?php echo url_for('index.php?id=' . h(u($nav_page['id']))); ?>"><?php echo h($nav_page['menu_name']); ?></a>
    </li>
    </ul>
<?php   } // while $nav_pages 
    } // if($nav_subject['id'] == $subject_id) 
  } // while $nav_subjects ?>
    </li>
<?php 
    mysqli_free_result($nav_subjects);
    mysqli_free_result($nav_pages); 
?>
```

I am pulling in the SQL from another page which is loaded correctly as the categories load and display correctly.

I will be grateful for any ideas.

I have also tried to echo back the sql result but nothing is shown.

I have now got it working with the following code:-

```
                                        <li>

                                        <?php $nav_subjects = find_all_subjects(['visible' => $visible]);
                                             while($nav_subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nav_subjects)) {?>
                                                 <span class="opener"><?php echo h($nav_subject['menu_name']); ?></span>
                                        <ul>
                                        <?php if($nav_subject['id'] == $subject_id);
                                        $nav_pages = find_pages_by_subject_id($nav_subject['id'], ['visible' => $visible]);
                                         while($nav_page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nav_pages)) { ?>
                                            <li><a href="<?php echo url_for('index.php?id=' . h(u($nav_page['id']))); ?>"><?php echo h($nav_page['menu_name']); ?></a></li>


                                    <?php } ?>
                                <?php } ?>
                                        </ul>
```

But now it is listing the secondary subjects as a child of the first instead of individual subjects of their own.

*********Resolved**********

please advise if you think the code could be better i've currently used :-

```
                                        <li>
                                        <?php $nav_subjects = find_all_subjects(['visible' => $visible]);?>
                                        <?php while($nav_subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nav_subjects)){?>
                                             <span class="opener"><?php echo h($nav_subject['menu_name']);?></span>
                                        <ul>
                                        <?php if($nav_subject['id'] == $subject_id);
                                        $nav_pages = find_pages_by_subject_id($nav_subject['id'], ['visible' => $visible]);
                                         while($nav_page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nav_pages)) { ?>
                                         <a href="<?php echo url_for('index.php?id=' . h(u($nav_page['id']))); ?>">
                                                <?php echo h($nav_page['menu_name']); ?></a>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                                <?php mysqli_free_result($nav_pages); ?>
                                        </ul>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                            <?php mysqli_free_result($nav_subjects); ?>
                                    </li>
```